# replacing the column of one csv file from another csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am working on an assignment i have two CSV files. First File Contains my whole data(shown Below)

#### First File:

```
  0  ID  Name                  Suburb      State   Postcode  Email                       Lat         Lon
0 0  1   Hurstville Clinic     Hurstville  NSW     1493      hurstville@myclinic.com.au  -33.975869  151.088939
1 1  2   Sydney Centre Clinic  Sydney      NSW     2000      sydney@myclinic.com.au      -33.867139  151.207114
2 2  3   Auburn Clinic         Auburn      NSW     2144      auburn@myclinic.com.au      -33.849322  151.033421
3 3  4   Riverwood Clinic      Riverwood   NSW     2210      riverwood@myclinic.com.au   -33.949859  151.052469
```

Second File contains the data Which i have to Replace with the first file `Email Column`.
I used Regex to convert the second file into HTML links.
This is what I've done to clean my data:

```
def clean(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['Email'] = df['Email'].apply(lambda x: x if '@' in str(x) else str(x)+'@myclinic.com.au')
    return df.to_csv('temp1.csv')
```

#### Second File output

```
Email
<a href="hurstville@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="sydney@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="auburn@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="riverwood@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="bay@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="harrington@myclinic.com.au"></a>
<a href="forest@myclinic.com.au"></a>
```

which is not correct. The above function is ommiting everything before the spaces in the email column and also ommmiting any row which has space before @ in the email column.

This is what I have to do:
a) Clean the data of file one (Two unwanted columns) and There are some spaces in the Email column as some addresses have spaces in the name and they can not be read in the final function.
b) The end output that i am getting is not the output that i want. it is ommiting 10 rows:

this is what I've done in file2.

```
emails = re.findall(r'\S+@\S+', text)
for x in range(0, len(emails)):
    emails[x] = '<a href="%s"></a>' % emails[x];
emails.insert(0, 'Email')

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in emails:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

here, text is a dictonary which contains my whole csv data. Insteading of calling CSV file i just copied whole content in my python file.

#### Final Output

```
    ID  Name    Suburb  State   Postcode    Email_Str   Lat Lon
0   1   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    <a href="hurstville@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -33.975869  151.088939
1   2   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    <a href="sydney@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -33.867139  151.207114
2   3   Auburn Clinic   Auburn  NSW 2144    <a href="auburn@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -33.849322  151.033421
3   4   Riverwood Clinic    Riverwood   NSW 2210    <a href="riverwood@myclinic.com.au"></a>    -33.949859  151.052469
4   6   Harrington Clinic   Harrington  NSW 2427    <a href="harrington@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -31.872153  152.689811
5   9   Benolong Clinic Benolong    NSW 2830    <a href="benolong@myclinic.com.au"></a> -32.413736  148.63938
6   11  Preston Clinic  Preston VIC 3072    <a href="preston@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -37.738736  145.000515
7   13  Douglas Clinic  Douglas VIC 3409    <a href="douglas@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -37.842988  144.892631
8   14  Mildura Clinic  Mildura VIC 3500    <a href="mildura@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -34.181714  142.163072
9   15  Broadford Clinic    Broadford   VIC 3658    <a href="broadford@myclinic.com.au"></a>    -37.203001  145.050171
10  16  Officer Clinic  Officer VIC 3809    <a href="officer@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -38.063056  145.40958
11  18  Langsborough Clinic Langsborough    VIC 3971    <a href="langsborough@myclinic.com.au"></a> -38.651487  146.675098
12  19  Brisbane Centre Clinic  Brisbane    QLD 4000    <a href="brisbane@myclinic.com.au"></a> -27.46758   153.027892
13  20  Robertson Clinic    Robertson   QLD 4109    <a href="robertson@myclinic.com.au"></a>    -27.565733  153.057213
14  22  Ipswich Clinic  Ipswich QLD 4305    <a href="ipswich@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -27.614604  152.760876
15  24  Caboolture Clinic   Caboolture  QLD 4510    <a href="caboolture@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -27.085007  152.951707
16  25  Booie Clinic    Booie   QLD 4610    <a href="booie@myclinic.com.au"></a>    -26.498426  151.935421
17  26  Rockhampton Clinic  Rockhampton QLD 4700    <a href="rockhampton@myclinic.com.au"></a>  -23.378941  150.512323
18  28  Cairns Clinic   Cairns  QLD 4870    <a href="cairns@myclinic.com.au"></a>   -16.925397  145.775178
19  29  Adelaide Centre Clinic  Adelaide    SA  5000    <a href="adelaide@myclinic.com.au"></a> -34.92577   138.599732
```

*My data is missing after final merging*

As you can see it is missing a lot of data.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the function `regex()` going to do? No parameters and you're doing nothing with a potential return value.

Comment: I forget to comment it.
it was a Different function call.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Where do `output` and `text` come from? Your second file already has the e-mails in it; what needs to change? The second file doesn't have an identifier to match up to rows in the first file; how do you expect to match them up? Additionally, you seem to be having multiple problems: you mention both undesired columns in a CSV file, you seem to be trying to scrub data somehow, and you're having trouble with the matching. Putting multiple problems in a single question makes it Too Broad. Please put only one problem in a question and make each one *very* clear.

Comment: Text is the dictionary that i made.
It just contains my whole CSV file data. Also, I am having problem fething data in that part.
i am going to update my question.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is but it seems that you're trying to convert the email text into an email link. You can do this:

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="' + x + '"></a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to merge two data-frames on the 'Email' column such that after merge you should get Email String from `DF2` merged with `DF1`.

- First we need to create a second column within DF2 that has email
  pattern matching DF1 (Email_Str).
- Next, we merge DF1, and DF2 on common Email column
- Further, we remove unwanted column
- Finally, rearrange columns to desired sequence.

Working code as below (using your data)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=",", engine="python")
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=",", engine="python")

def get_email(x):
    return ''.join(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', x))

df2.columns = ['Email_Str'] 
df2['Email']=df2['Email_Str'].apply(get_email) 
df2 = df2[['Email','Email_Str']]  
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Email').drop(['Email'], axis=1) 
df3 = df3[[u'ID', u'Name', u'Suburb', u'State', u'   
      Postcode',u'Email_Str', u'Lat', u'Lon', ]]
```

**Result:**

```
>>> df3
   ID                   Name      Suburb State   Postcode  \
0   1      Hurstville Clinic  Hurstville   NSW       1493   
1   2   Sydney Centre Clinic      Sydney   NSW       2000   
2   3          Auburn Clinic      Auburn   NSW       2144   
3   4       Riverwood Clinic   Riverwood   NSW       2210   

                                   Email_Str        Lat         Lon  
0  <a href="hurstville@myclinic.com.au"></a> -33.975869  151.088939  
1      <a href="sydney@myclinic.com.au"></a> -33.867139  151.207114  
2      <a href="auburn@myclinic.com.au"></a> -33.849322  151.033421  
3   <a href="riverwood@myclinic.com.au"></a> -33.949859  151.052469  
>>>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Where have you stored df3 values?

Comment: i saw it... But i've to store it in a CSV file.
can you help me how?

Comment: i stored it using df3.to_csv.. but now in the final output.csv my data fields are missing.
I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what is the problem.
My original data have spaces in the Email Column.
So can anyone update my regex Function?

```
def clean(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['Email'] = df['Email'].apply(lambda x: x if '@' in str(x) else str(x)+'@myclinic.com.au')
    return df.to_csv('temp1.csv')
```